# ThingsBoards Cloud How to change the default SUBSCRIBE topic of an MQTT communication using the thingsboard broker

Tags: javascript, iot, thingsboard

I have a question below

Is it possible to change the default **SUBSCRIBE** topic of an MQTT communication using the thingsboard broker? (**thingsboard.cloud:1883**) default SUBSCRIBE topic (**v1/devices/me/rpc/request/+**)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, yet.
By now you can only change the Default topics for Telemetry & Attributes.

This can be configured via Device Profile:

[image]

Comment: hello @mdeuchert  and thanks for the help

I really need to change the only the subscribe parameter, thanks